# Como enviar JSON como resposta do post

Tags: php, json

Tenho a página A com o seguinte código para enviar um POST para a página B:

```
function curlPost($url, $dados) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($dados));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}

$executarPost = curlPost($url, $dados);
$resposta     = json_decode($executarPost, true);
```

Como envio um JSON com alguns dados da página B (página que recebeu o POST) para a página A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer o uso do `echo` na página do B juntamente com o `json_encode`. Após enviar a requisição do A para o B, o A esperará uma resposta do B. Sendo assim, o B utilizará a combinação do `echo` e `json_encode` para enviar a resposta em formato JSON para o A.

Nesse exemplo estou simulando que A envie os dados os dados `id` com um valor e `nome_topico` com outro valor para B. Portanto, o código do B abaixo responderá os mesmos dados enviados pelo A (que pode ser qualquer dado definido pelo desenvolvedor):

```
B.php:

<?php

if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['nome_topico'])) 
{
    $resposta = array(
        'id' => $_POST['id'],
        'nome_topico' => $_POST['nome_topico']
    );

    echo json_encode($resposta);
}
```

No seu exemplo, a resposta de B estará na variável `$executarPost`.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda, Obrigado!